# What is the purpose of \protect?

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

I've never understood the purpose of the command `\protect`? When and why should it be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands

Comment: And refer this FAQ: http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/FAQ-en/html/FAQ-protect.html

Comment: @LeoLiu you may edit your link: it seems dead.

Comment: @ManuH http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-protect.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To understand how to use `\protect` you need to understand the concept of *fragile commands* and to understand this concept, you need to understand what a moving argument is. Some commands called fragile commands causes an error when they use a moving argument. It's a command that expands into illegal TeX code during the save process. Some arguments are called moving arguments because they may be "moved" to other places in the document. A fragile command that appears in a moving argument must be preceded by a `\protect` command. For example,

- sectioning commands
- arguments of `\caption` commands
- commands that produce page headings

An example :

```
\caption{Beautiful picture from \protect \citeauthor{allan}
  \protect \shortcite{allan}}
```

Comment: "[A fragile command is a command that] expands into illegal TeX code during the save process." - What does this mean? What is the "save" process? How does a command that expands into illegal TeX successfully compile? Are there circumstances wherein a so-called "fragile command" expands into *legal* TeX?

Comment: I'm with @Jake here. While the answer technically answers the question, it leaves open a lot of questions. However this question is a duplicate anyway and the answer on the other question as linked on top is far more detailed.

Comment: This technically isn't even an answer to the question.It didn't answer *what is the purpose of the \protect command*?, it just lists a few cases where I need one.This doesn't explain why LaTeX can't just put the protect in for me or what it actually does.

Comment: The information here https://latexref.xyz/_005cprotect.html seems elucidative.