# Referencing subfigures in main caption (with \subfloat and \subref)

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, subcaption

I've used subfloat to include subfigures, with their relevant labels but with empty captions. what I'm going to do is to reference these figures with \subref in the main caption of the figure. But what I get is only ?? signs in the caption [main caption]. I can't figure out what's the problem. this is what I have:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][]
{
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{signal}
\label{signal_model}
}
\subfloat[][]
{
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{amplitude}
\label{amplitude_mod}
}
\caption{phase noise variability: \subref{signal model} some text \subref{amplitude_mod} some other text}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You need a subcaption nevertheless, even if empty, so that the subfigure is at least labelled.

Comment: can you turn your snippet into a complete MWE?

Comment: Actually I want to have labeled subfigures, i.e. to have (a) (b) (c) etc. below each subfigure without sub-captions. but I want to cite or refer them in the main caption of the figure (I thought it's possible with '\subref')

Comment: I got the answer, but I think something missing with subcaption package:

"The subcaption package was updated to version 1.1. It got a new option for selecting a format used by \subref, and a new command called \phantomsubcaption for referencing a sub-figure without caption. Furthermore the subcaption package documentation was enhanced regarding references."

Comment: If you are really using the `subcaption` package (and not the `subfig` one) please use `\subcaptionbox` instead of `\subfloat` and put the `\label` inside the caption text, not inside the sub-figure body.

Comment: Turns out `refcheck` can also mess with `\subref`. Was getting `??sub@<ref>` instead of `(a)`, and it showed properly as `(a)` when I turned off refcheck. Note that `\protect\subref` while `refcheck` was on didn't fix it.

Comment: Same behaviour as @Sterling's with `showkeys` instead of `refcheck`: including `\protect` does not help, but turning off `showkeys` makes the subrefs appear properly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to `\protect` the `\subref` command in the caption:

```
\caption{Phase noise variability: \protect\subref{signal_model} some text 
  \protect\subref{amplitude_mod} some other text}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image-a}\label{signal_model}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image-b}\label{amplitude_mod}}

\caption{Phase noise variability: \protect\subref{signal_model} some text 
  \protect\subref{amplitude_mod} some other text}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 and BIG thanks for this .. I was struggling with this (my documentclass prohibits use of caption, and therefore subcaption, where for some reason \subref does not need \protect)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just wanted to add the reason for using `\protect`: The command `\subref{}` is a _fragile_ command, and `\caption` has a _moving argument_. The `\protect` command is needed whenever we use a fragile command in a moving argument.

Comment: @hadi That doesn't really do much to explain the need to `\protext` that `\subref` call. It works perfectly fine in the `subfigure` package, so at a first look it is a regression in behaviour. Why is making `\subref`fragile an advantage in any way, other than breaking code which used to work?

Comment: @hadi - thanks! Now a newbie like me still needs to read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect) and then have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) (harder still).

Comment: Thanks, can someone explain what protect does?

Comment: Is it possible to automatically display them in the correct order? That is, instead of manually referring to (a) before (b) in the main caption, let this be done automatically?

Comment: @samwolfe Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: @egreg Please see this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636701/automatic-subcaption-listing

Comment: When I use `\protect\subref`, I get the letters, but not with parenthesis around them as you do. why do you get with parenthesis but I don't?