# floatrow package, subfigures and cross referencing

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

I think the question has not been posted already.

Here is my problem :

I wanted several subfigures within one. I used "subcaption" package at first, as it's the newest. But it appeared that it's not possible to reposition the subcaption next to the figure (instead of below it). For that, I had to use "floatrow" package, which is incompatible with "subcaption" package.

BUT, when I cross-reference the subfigure in the general figure caption, instead of 'blabla (a)', shows 'blabla 1(a)' (1 being the figure number). I don't want the figure number when I cross ref in the same fig !

Thanks a lot for any help !

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % for table, doesn't matter here
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 5cm,keepaspectratio]{bigpicture1}\label{fig:sub_ref_1}}
  \\[10pt] 

  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 5cm,keepaspectratio]{bigpicture2}\label{fig:sub_ref_2}}
\caption{I want to cross ref. Now I can only obtain that : \ref{fig:sub_ref_1}, and that : \ref{fig:sub_ref_2} }
\label{fig:fig_1_label}

 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Compiled :]

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

It seems that there is a problem with my TeX distribution and/or OS. 
Let's see : what worked for me (MacOS 10.8.3, TeXshop 3.11)

```
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
% \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % for table
\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

  \sidesubfloat[]{ \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 5cm,keepaspectratio]{bigpicture1}\label{fig:sub_ref_1} }
  \\[10pt] 

  \sidesubfloat[]{ \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height = 5cm,keepaspectratio]{bigpicture1}\label{fig:sub_ref_2} }

  \caption{I want to cross ref. Now I can only obtain that : \protect\subref{fig:sub_ref_1}, and that : \protect\subref{fig:sub_ref_2} }
  \label{fig:fig_1_label}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So I had to

- write `\protect\subref{...}` instead of `\ref{..}`
- not write `\usepackage{caption}`

The solution is actually a  derivative of another question : [Referencing subfigures in main caption (with \subfloat and \subref)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62636/referencing-subfigures-in-main-caption-with-subfloat-and-subref)

:)