# How to cite subfigure numbers for caption of the parent figure?

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am trying to cite subfigure numbers in the caption of the parent figure as shown in MWE. It works but I always get the following error which I cannot remove:

**Error**

```
Line 15: Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. [...f{fig:sub_fig_B} B \subref{fig:sub_fig_C}}]
Line 15: Paragraph ended before \caption@ydblarg was complete. [...f{fig:sub_fig_B} B \subref{fig:sub_fig_C}}]
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\label{fig:sub_fig_A} \includegraphics[width=67mm]
    {example-image-a}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{fig:sub_fig_B} \includegraphics[width=67mm]
    {example-image-b}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\label{fig:sub_fig_C} \includegraphics[width=67mm]
    {example-image-c}}
    \subfloat[]{\label{fig:sub_fig} \includegraphics[width=67mm]
    {example-image}}
    \caption{Caption for \subref{fig:sub_fig_A} A \subref{fig:sub_fig_B} B \subref{fig:sub_fig_C}}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

***How to remove this error?***

Comment: See [Referencing subfigures in main caption (with \subfloat and \subref)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62700)