# Automatic subcaption listing

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, captions, subcaption

Imagine I have the following figure

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1c}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1e}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1f}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\caption{(a) A caption. (b) Another caption. (c) Yet another caption. (d) So many captions. (e) Really. (f) I'm done with captions.} 
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

which gives

[image]

**My question:** is it possible to automatically label the subfigures so that I don't have to write (a), (b), ... (f) by hand on the figure caption, and keep their order (as set by the mini pages)?

In some sense, it would be nice to simply write the caption under each subfigure but make these captions appear, **automatically labelled in the correct ordering**, in the figure's main caption. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62636/referencing-subfigures-in-main-caption-with-subfloat-and-subref), but it still doesn't fix the automatic ordering problem.

Comment: You already use `\label`, so one could use `\ref` or possibly `\subref`. although that seems like more work, not less.  I take it you want something like `\footnote` to create the caption as you go.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Those are nice options, though I still have to manually write them in order. Ideally, a subcaption would be associated with a certain subfigure and automatically displayed (in the correct order) in the main caption.

Answer (score 1):

The creates a global macro (`\thecaption`) containing the accumulated subcaptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\thecaption}{}% reserve global name

\newcommand{\mysubcaption}[1]{% #1 = text
  \caption{}%
  \ifnum\value{subfigure}=1 
    \xdef\thecaption{(\thesubfigure)~#1}%
  \else
    \xdef\thecaption{\thecaption, (\thesubfigure)~#1}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]% friends don't let friends use H
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \mysubcaption{A caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\floatsep
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \mysubcaption{Another caption}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \mysubcaption{Yet another caption}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \mysubcaption{So many captions}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\floatsep
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \mysubcaption{Really}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \mysubcaption{I'm done with captions}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\caption{\thecaption.}% Note the period.
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_samwolfe_ac_captions_seq
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\delayedsubcaption}{m}
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_samwolfe_ac_label_int
    \caption{ \label{ac@\int_to_arabic:n { \g_samwolfe_ac_label_int}} }
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_samwolfe_ac_captions_seq
      {
        \exp_not:N \protect
        (\exp_not:N \subref {ac@\int_to_arabic:n { \g_samwolfe_ac_label_int}})
        \exp_not:n { \nobreakspace #1 }
      }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printsubcaptions}{}
  {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_samwolfe_ac_captions_seq { .~ }.
  }

\int_new:N \g_samwolfe_ac_label_int
\seq_new:N \g_samwolfe_ac_captions_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Main}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \delayedsubcaption{A caption}
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
        \delayedsubcaption{Another caption}
        \label{fig1b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \delayedsubcaption{Yet another caption}
        \label{fig1c}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \delayedsubcaption{So many captions}
        \label{fig1d}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \delayedsubcaption{Really}
        \label{fig1e}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \delayedsubcaption{I'm done with captions}
        \label{fig1f}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\caption{\printsubcaptions}
\label{fig1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can add whatever you want to the main caption. Disposable labels are created, but you can add your own for reference.

[image]

I changed your `\quad` to a blank line, which is “the right thing to do”.