# \endnote inside \author tag

Tags: titles, koma-script, endnotes

I have a rather complicated document of the {scrartcl} class, derived from the .tex file I downloaded off this page http://www.howtotex.com/templates/template-added-two-column-color-article/

I try to use the endnotes package to specify the authors' affiliations (it won't fit in the template prescribed format). Sadly I cannot use the \endnote{} macros inside the \author{} field. Compilation fails on that line with:

```
./openpr.tex:81: Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
```

I have tried the enotez package but the line where I put the endnote fails with:

```
./openpr.tex:81: Use of \enotez_endnote_aux:w doesn't match its definition.
```

I get the error with this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn,hyperref]{scrartcl}                        % KOMA-article class
\usepackage[english]{babel}                                     % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{endnotes}                                           % Used for annoting author affiliations at the ened

\usepackage{titling}                                                            % For custom titles

\title{Concepts}                    % Title of article goes here

\author{Lala \endnote{a}}                                   % Authors' names goes here
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Apparently it works if I remove \usepackage{titling}, but I need that to make my title sexy :(

Could you guys help me get an endnotes' section with all my author affiliations?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @texenthusiast Ok, I updated it.

Comment: Once again: It works for me _without_ and **with** `titling`! Otherwise you must provide a proper MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit in reaction to comments for using the same endnotemark more than once:*

### With `endnotes`:

Use `\endnotemark[number]` and `\endnotetext[number]`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\title{Concepts}
\author{Lala\endnotemark[1], Lilo\endnotemark[2],
        Lolita\endnotemark[1], Lulu\endnotemark[3]}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\endnotetext[1]{Institute ABC}
\endnotetext[2]{Institute A\&O}
\endnotetext[3]{Institute XYZ}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

### With `enotez`:

Starting from version 0.6 you can use the following approach. The package is now able to use a label-ref mechanism, so you do not have to keep track of the number.

<sup>For older versions see [answer’s revision history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/104314/5).</sup>

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enotez}
  \makeatletter % taken from documentation
  \def\endnotemark{\@ifnextchar[{\@endnotemark}{\@endnotemark[\theendnote]}}
  \def\@endnotemark[#1]{\enotezwritemark{\enmarkstyle#1}}
  \makeatother

\title{Concepts}
\author{Lala\endnote{Institute ABC}\label{lala}, Lilo\endnote{Institute A\&O},
        Lolita\endnotemark[\ref{lala}], Lulu\endnote{Institute XYZ}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

---

*Original answer:*

### With `endnotes`:

Using `\endnote` with `\protect` works fine.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\title{Concepts}
\author{Lala\protect\endnote{abc}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

### With `enotez`:

You have to use `\protect` again:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enotez}

\title{Concepts}
\author{Lala\protect\endnote{endnote}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

---

For `\protect` see also [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) and [Alain Matthes’ answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12699/9237) to [What is the purpose of \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect)

Comment: The enotez code you just gave me returns ./openpr.tex:8: Undefined control sequence. for the line with either \theendnotes or \printendnotes on it

Comment: No error here. Try a second compilation, it may be a remnant of the last run.

Comment: Nope - apparently it will not run unless I add a number in brackets after \endnote - this is a minor inconvenience, but for now it's ok. Sadly, in my document the \maketitle command stopped working after I implemented this. I am still trying to find out why, as the minimal example works.

Comment: General remark: Read carefully, what the real meaning of “minimal working examples” is. Apparently you removed too much and did not show us, that you intend to use custom numbers. For the second: In first revision I used `\endnotemark` and `\endtnotetext`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/104314/2. (But on the other side you left packages and options in, which are not needed …)

Comment: I fixed the \maketitle issue. But I still cannot use \endnote without specifying the number in brackets. Depending on whether or not I import the titling package in the header your code eitherfails at \printendnotes (if no titling) or at \maketitle (if titling). Also, I do not intend to use custom numbers - what gave you that Idea? I would rather just not be mentioning them the entire time.

Comment: Which version of `enotez` do you have? Here I use version v0.5a from 2013/03/18. No issue with custom numbers here and `titling` included!

Comment: How can I find out what version I have? I installed enotez as part of a bigger metapackage with different versioning. Also, what exactly do you mean by custom numbers? I don't want that, I want enotez to do my numbering automatically (also, how do I call an endnote I have already defined? the enotez docs don't say much...

Comment: Ok, that might be it, I'm using version 0.3.... So how do I call an endnote I have already defined?

Comment: @TheChymera type `\theendnotes` at the place where you want all of them.

Comment: @texenthusiast Not that, I meant calling a second reference to one of the endnotes

Comment: @TheChymera `\endnote[num of authors]{..}` format for multiple authors. 
`

Comment: @TheChymera What do you mean with “call an endnote … already defined”? Edit your MWE (here more a minimal not working example)!

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is not exactly what you needed, I tried Using [scrartcl](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) class built-in macro options `\thanks{}`[Page 57 Ch:3]  for footnotes and `\and{}`[Page 58, Ch:3] for including multiple authors.

There are many `header, footnote, title` options mentioned for this class , there is no need to use additional packages to tailor it. KOMA-article classes are most flexible enough.

To achieve `endnotes` effect `\appendix` or `\newenvironment` can be defined.

```
  \documentclass[DIV=calc,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn
  ,hyperref]{scrartcl}  % KOMA-article class
  \usepackage[english]{babel}  % Englishlanguage/hyphenation
 %\usepackage{endnotes}  % Used forannoting author affiliations at the end
   \usepackage{titling}    % For custom titles                                                         
   \title{Concepts} % Title of article goes here
   \author{{Lala,Dept,University} \thanks{Lala Team},\and{ Others,Research     
  Center} \thanks{Others Members},\and{ Also, Teacher, School} \thanks{Also 
  People}} % Authors' names goes here 
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is sadly not what I am looking for, as I do not want this info cluttering my first page (or pushing up the text section on any other page) I would like to have the affiliations listed at the document end similarly to the bibliography.

Comment: @TheChymera sorry may be i misunderstood, i will try if i can place them at end of document.

Comment: @TheChymera I could not using in-built class options, i feel sleepy. May be i will wait for other's suggestion, for time being use `endnotes` package, it works fine.