# rotatebox symbol in caption generates error

Tags: captions, rotating

Following minimal example doesn't work and generates an error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  FIGURE
\caption{$\blacksquare$ result of; \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}}%
\end{figure}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}
\end{document}
```

The error message says:

```
rotatebox-in-caption.tex|7| Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
|| <inserted text> 
||                 \par 
|| l.7 ...; \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}}
```

Do I have to wrap the `\rotatebox` in a certain box to make it work?

Comment: You can read for the underlying cause http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect

Comment: It'll probably come down to using `\caption[Stuff for the list of figures goes here]{$\blacksquare$ result of; \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}}`. You might be able to `\protect` some of it if you really want it in the `lof`

Comment: Just add `\protect` in front of `\rotatebox`, that is, `\protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{...}`, when it's in the argument of `\caption`.

Comment: using `\protect` solves the problem. @percusse I checked your link. What does `\protect` actually do to allow the fragile(?) command `\rotatebox` within a moving env. such as the `\caption`. What does it have to do with the `lof` what cmhughes was mentioning (there is no list of figures)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\rotatebox` is [fragile](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-protect), see also: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/16967)

Inside "moving arguments" as in the argument of `\caption` fragile macros can be protected by prefixing them with `\protect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  FIGURE
\caption{$\blacksquare$ result of;
 \protect\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}}%
\end{figure}
Text: \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\blacksquare$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Making fragile macros robust

- Package **`makerobust`** defines macro **`\MakeRobustCommand`**. It adds the LaTeX's protection layer for the macro in the same way as LaTeX's `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

  ```
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{makerobust}
    \MakeRobustCommand\rotatebox
    ...
    \caption{... \rotatebox ...}
  ```

  `\rotatebox` is no longer fragile and can be used without `\protect`.
- Package **`etoolbox`** defines **`\robustify`** that redefines a macro with e-TeX's `\protected`:

  ```
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \robustify\rotatebox
    ...
    \caption{... \rotatebox ...}
  ```

  This also makes `\rotatebox` robust without the need of `\protect` for this macro.

Comment: an update some years later.... `\rotatebox` is robust in current releases so the original document will run without error.