# How to use scalebox in captions?

Tags: captions, scaling

This code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test \scalebox{3.0}{$\int$} test.
\begin{table}
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  A & B \\
  C & D 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test \scalebox{3.0}{$\int$} test.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives me the error message:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
```

The result looks how I want it to, though...

What should I do?

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of \protect?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12698/3954) and [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/3954).

Comment: Is there a reason why you won't use `$\displaystyle\int$` in the caption? The enlarged text-style integral one gets via `\scalebox{3.0}{$\int$}` is not at all centered on the math axis, making it look accidentally comical. This is an effect you are (I would hope!) not actively trying to create, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options. First one is to `\protect` `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test \scalebox{3.0}{$\int$} test.
\begin{table}
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  A & B \\
  C & D
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test \protect\scalebox{3.0}{$\int$} test.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Second one is to use the optional argument of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test \scalebox{3.0}{$\int$} test.
\begin{table}
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  A & B \\
  C & D
\end{tabular}
\caption[Test $\int$ test.]{Test \scalebox{3.0}{$\int$} test.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This happens as the contents of `\caption` are movable (i.e., fragile) as they may be used in `lof` and you have to `\protect` commands (from expanding) used inside the argument.

Comment: I strongly recommend your second method, as there's probably little point in producing an enlarged text-style integral sign in the List of Tables. However, I think that a third option -- `\displaystyle\int` -- is still better: the integral sign will then be set correctly on the math axis rather stick out bizarely above it.