# \bcode in \section does not work -- because of \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

there seems to be a problem regarding `\bcode` in `chapter` ETC environment.
It seems that LaTeX cannot solve the `\tableofcontents` entry:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}
\begin{document}
\title{\bcode{*nou=s}}
\author{\bcode{*poihtiko/s}}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{\bcode{*e)ntele/xeia}}

\bcode{dia/noia}

\end{document}
```

If you `%` the `\tableofcontents` it does work flawlessly.
(Just put the other `\bcode` in to test out what does work and what does not)

Is there a solution or a work around for that problem?

Kind Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: I already tried `\protect\bcode{nou=s}` -- it didnt work either.

Comment: Try `\section{\protect\bcode{*e)ntele/xeia}}`

Comment: `\protect` does work, but delete the old toc first.

Comment: Ah...just found another `\section` with `\bcode` in it, that i did not properly protect. Now it does work. Thank you and sorry for being a bother ;)

Comment: @esdd Apparently, your hint helped :-) Wanna make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fragile commands in moving arguments must be preceded by `\protect`, see [What is the purpose of \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12699) and [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/43317).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}
\begin{document}
\title{\bcode{*nou=s}}
\author{\bcode{*poihtiko/s}}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{\protect\bcode{*e)ntele/xeia}}% <-

\bcode{dia/noia}

\end{document}
```

[image]