# moving captions to bottom of figure/table

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I have a document where all the descriptions currently appear above the figure/table. That is simply how I wrote everything. However, for publishing purposes the descriptions of figures and tables need to be below the figure/table. Is there a way to automatically get them to appear that way or do I have to do this by hand? Here is a sample of how one of my figures looks:

```
\begin{figure}
\protect\caption{Title of Figure\label{fig:F1}}


This is a description of figure 1. It talks about what is in the figure and where the data comes from. It's a really good description.

\vspace{1cm}


\centering{}\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/fig_1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What is your document class?

Comment: If you do `\usepackage{float}` `\restylefloat{figure}` all `figure` captions should appear below the `figure`. `\restylefloat{table}` will do the same for `table`s.

Comment: @Bernard: class is a custom class derived from report

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: would that move the title of the figure (in this case "Title of Figure") or would that move the description ("This is a description of figure 1. It talks ...")?

Comment: without checking how the `report` class positions captions, my advice is to input the data in the location where you want to see it in the output.  with luck, it will be placed there; if the document class repositions it, then ask the question here of how to more it.

Comment: Sure, but the normal behaviour of  latex  is to let the caption at the point where it's called. So write it *after* your tables or figures.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: i'm attempting to avoid re-positioning everything by hand since there are a lot of figures and tables. hoping there was some automated way to do this?

Comment: @Bernard: trying to avoid moving all of them by hand, see previous comment

Comment: You can try a `search & replace`   with regular expressions.

Comment: @Alex, the `\usepackage{float}` would unfortunately only move the title of the figure, not the description. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: `\protect\caption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really seem to be only two options:

1. Use the package `floatrow` as follows:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{floatrow}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}
   \protect\caption[position=bottom]{Title of Figure\label{fig:F1}}

   This is a description of figure 1. It talks about what is in the   
   figure and where the data comes from. It's a really good description.

   \vspace{1cm}


   \centering{}\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

Which produces

[image]

Which means, unfortunately, you'd have to move whatever further image descriptions you have into the caption (in this case, ending up with the line of code

```
\protect\caption[position=bottom]{Title of Figure\label{fig:F1} 
This is a description of figure 1. It talks about what is in the figure 
and where the data comes from. It's a really good description.}
```

Giving

[image]

Which, depending on how many graphics you have that have extra description not in the caption, could be a real pain.

2. You could bite the bullet and go through all graphics and move the location of the text:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}

   \vspace{1cm}


   \centering{}\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}


   \protect\caption[position=bottom]{Title of Figure\label{fig:F1}}
   This is a description of figure 1. It talks about what is in the 
   figure and where the data comes from. It's a really good description.
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

Which gives

[image]

This would be even more of a pain than the first option, unfortunately.

So, it seems that you have to bite the bullet one way or the other. *However* I will keep looking for another solution, though at this point I am semi-doubtful there is one that will help you.

Comment: I wondering: (i) why is used `\centering{}` instead simple `\centering`, and (ii) why is need `\protect` before caption?

Comment: @Zarko, I assume the brackets on `\centering{}` are used to isolate the effect to just the figure. As for `\protect`, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect).

Comment: The question doesn't justify, why is this necessary. To my opinion this only require surplus typing :-)

Comment: @Zarko, really, the only thing the question asks is how to fix the caption, so I didn't really bother with the rest. =)

Comment: @heather: cool, thanks! this is basically what i'm doing. i think i will just put in the effort and move everything. thanks!

Comment: @Alex, glad this helped, and sorry I couldn't find anything better. =) Good luck with your publication!