# Clipped symbol in table caption

Tags: tables, captions, adjustbox, clip

I want to place a clipped math symbol in table caption.
This MWE works until I uncomment the marked line

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Clipped symbol in table caption
%\clipbox{.7ex 0ex 0ex 0ex}{$k$}          % <--- Uncomment this line
}
Clipped symbol in table body \clipbox{.7ex 0ex 0ex 0ex}{$k$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and gives this

[image: No clipped symbol in caption]

But when I do uncomment the above line, i get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempa ->\@nil

l.7 }

?
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put `\protect` before `\clipbox`.

For the explanation, see here: [What is the purpose of \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Clipped symbol in table caption
\protect\clipbox{.7ex 0ex 0ex 0ex}{$k$}          % <--- Uncomment this line
}
Clipped symbol in table body \clipbox{.7ex 0ex 0ex 0ex}{$k$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]