create a blank line in table of contents
I'm trying to create a blank line at the bottom of a page in my table of contents.  In the corresponding chapter I tried:
\textcolor{white}{\subsection[\textcolor{white}{t}]{t}}

Which makes that section number and name invisible on the chapter page (as intended) but the numbering is still visible in the toc, as shown below:

Is there a way to hide the numbering as well?  (Or just create a white rectangle of a specified height in the toc, or a different way of adding vspace there.)

try \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1cm}}

Or, \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}.

For safety purpose, can use \protect along with \addtocontents, i.e., \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}

@MadyYuvi Thanks.  Why is the \protect necessary?

@Nate Please refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/what-is-the-purpose-of-protect


I'm trying to create a blank line [...] in my table of contents.

I suggest you insert the instruction
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}

immediately after
\subsubsection{Duals \& Compounds}

(\vspace* instead of \vspace will work too.)


\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{10}  % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{9}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{4}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip % just for this example

\subsubsection{Duals \& Compounds}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
\dots

\subsubsection{More Stuff}

\end{document}

